# Get AWS S3 Upload URL - NodeJs AWS-SDK

Tags: javascript, node.js, async-await, promise, aws-sdk

I'm pretty sure I'm missing something very obvious here, but:

I'm uploading a file to an s3 bucket using `aws-sdk` as follows:

```
const awsURL = await s3.upload(params, (err, data) => {
    if (err) {
        console.log(err);
        return null;
    }
    console.log(`File uploaded successfully. ${data.Location}`);
    return data.Location;
});
return awsURL;
```

I'm able to log the upload url successfully, however the `awsURL` returned is an array, not the `data.Location` value - shouldn't the `data.Location` be returned from the callback?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Convert `s3.upload` to return a promise:

```
const data = await s3.upload(params).promise(); // this line
console.log(`File uploaded successfully. ${data.Location}`);
return data.Location;
```